# Failed to resize camera preview with setLayoutParams

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, preview

I am a new to Android and I am developing a camera app. I use a surfaceview to display camera preview which works fine. And then use setLayoutParams() to resize the surfaceview which not work. The size of surfaceview not changed.

anything wrong with my code ?

Appreciate very much if any suggestion or words.

Thanks a lot !

My code:

```
//init surfaceview and surfaceholder
private void initSurHolderRear()
{
    if ( null == mSurViewRear )
    {
        mSurViewRear = new SurfaceView(this);
    }

    WindowManager.LayoutParams parms;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        parms = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                1, 1,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        parms.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
    }
    else
    {
        parms = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                1, 1,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        parms.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
    }

    ( (WindowManager) ( this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) ) ).addView(mSurViewRear, parms);
    mSurHolderRear = mSurViewRear.getHolder();
    mSurHolderRear.addCallback(this);
}


//start camera preview
private void startPreview() {

    try {
        mCamRear.setPreviewDisplay(mSurHolderRear);
        mCamRear.startPreview();

        startRearRecording(mSurHolderRear);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Failed to startPreview, e: " + e);
    }
}

//resize camera preview
public void resizePreview()
{
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams parms = mSurViewRear.getLayoutParams();
    parms.width = 1000;
    parms.height = 1000;

    mSurViewRear.setLayoutParams(parms);
}
```

Comment: You are not calling the function resize preview?

Comment: Sure. I call resizePreview() somewhere else just not mentioned in my post. Thanks you for you reply !

Comment: And actually, I tested mSurViewRear.setBackgroundColor() in resizePreview(). It works. But failed to change the size :(

Comment: You might want to set the LayoutParams from somewhere else rather than ViewGroup